# Qt creator does not detect opencv

Tags: qt, opencv, include

I am trying to run a program in Qt5.6 with openCV3.1, but no matter what I do, it does not detect openCV include.

**Projects -> Build Environment -> Include** :
I added `C:\opencv\opencv3.1.0\opencv\build\include`

**Projects -> Build Environment -> LIB**:
I added `C:\opencv\opencv3.1.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib`

However, still in the code there is a yellow line indicating that it doesn't detect opencv:

[image]

and there are lots of errors like this:

[image]

The environment variable for openCV is also set as:

> **C:\opencv\opencv3.1.0\opencv\build**

How should I install Qt with openCV to avoid these problems?

Comment: does QtCreator use visual c++ as a compiler or minGW (identical compiler must be used) and make sure you use debug libs for debug build and release libs for release build.

Comment: Only visual c++ is used. I am using debug build, but for libs I just added the path of `C:\opencv\opencv3.1.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib` to Path variable.

Comment: you'll have to add the libs to the project as in the answer. But instead of opencv310.lib use the opencv310d.lib if you are building in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **.pro** file, add the following lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\opencv3.1.0\opencv\build\include
LIBS += -LC:\opencv\opencv3.1.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib \
    opencv310.lib \
```

And also you need to add the `.dll` file's path `C:\opencv\opencv3.1.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin` to the system path (this time you need to restart the Qt IDE)